# Box-shadow is not showing or z-index

Tags: html, z-index, css

i have tried as much i know about this stuff but failed to show box-shadow over the image.

http://thesameffect.com/healthy-habits-and-distinctions/#related-posts

i want to show shadow overlayed on the images. same like as ..

http://thesameffect.com/blog/

Please kindly help me..

**HTML :**

```
<div class="related-posts">
    <h3 class="related-title">Related Posts</h3>
    <ul id="related-posts" class="related-list">
        <li>
            <a title="Permanent Link toHow Genetics and Epigentics Relate to Your Health and Fitness" rel="bookmark" href="http://TheSamEffect.com/how-genetics-and-epigentics-relate-to-your-health-and-fitness/">
                <img class="attachment-Header Square" width="297" height="200" title="genes2" alt="genes2" src="http://TheSamEffect.com/wp-content/uploads/genes2-297x200.jpg">
                <span class="related-heading">How Genetics and Epigentics Relate to Your Health and Fitness</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            ...
        </li>   

        <li>
            ...
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.related-posts ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.related-list li {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000 inset;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    list-style: none outside none !important;
    margin: 0.25em !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 216px;
}

.related-posts ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.related-posts a {
    color: #F4F4F4;
}

.related-list img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.related-heading {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: Conv_resea-bolditalic,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif,georgia;
    font-size: 16px;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90.5%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

PHP - WP Codes :

*Thats how i am extracting images from genesis.*

```
            $img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'Header Square' ) ) : '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/related.png" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';

            $related .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to' . get_the_title() . '">' . $img . '<span class="related-heading">' . get_the_title() . '</span></a></li>';
```

after doing all this stuff i am still unable to see box-shadow, Actually shadow is there at its actual place but due to z-index i think i am unable to visible shadow.

please kindly help me to resolve the issue.

### thank you.

**After Solution:**

The following code just show the image url in Genesis.

genesis_get_image( array( 'format' => 'url' ) );

Comment: Do you have `:hover` defined for the `li` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/esnLn/)

http://jsfiddle.net/esnLn/

Set the image as div background

Comment: its good idea, but i am extracting image links from Genesis WP framwork.. like 
                    $img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'Header Square' ) ) : '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/related.png" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';
 
                    $related .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to' . get_the_title() . '">' . $img . '<span class="related-heading">' . get_the_title() . '</span></a></li>';

Comment: i finally figure out how to extract just image url in Genesis .. the code is **genesis_get_image( array( 'format' => 'url') );**

Answer (score 0):

Your shadow is on the list item which has an inset shadow, and the image in the list item covers it. One way around this is to set the list item backround image to your image and remove the image itself.

Based on your update you can try this:

```
$img = genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'Header Square' ) );
$related .= '<li style="background-image:url('.$img.')"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to' . get_the_title() . '"><span class="related-heading">' . get_the_title() . '</span></a></li>';
```

Comment: how can i do that .. its related post area. it is supposed too be changed all the time. when you refresh the page you will disover the these related post change again and again.

Comment: What code builds the related posts code? You would want to modify that to not generate the img tag and use the image as the background for the list item.

Comment: mate i edit the main question and added the codes ... which i am using to extract images from WP Genesis framework .. Please check PHP codes above.

Comment: mate **genesis_get_image()** image tag too :(

Comment: I don't follow your last comment.

Comment: mate genesis_get_image() return <img src="image/url" alt="title of image" /> although i just need **image/url**, so i check the Genesis files and discover that we can use **genesis_get_image( array( 'format' => 'url' ) );** to extract **only url**

Comment: Ah, ok. Yeah as I said it's hard to debug this way since I don't have access to this genesis API but based on the small code sample you posted that was as close as I could get.